# Как остановить Foreground Service

Tags: java, android

Ситуация такая. У меня есть приложение которое запускает при нажатии на CheckBox сервис, который работает, даже когда приложение прекращает работу, код внизу. Когда я снова захожу в приложение при нажатии на CheckBox в настройке я хочу отключать этот сервис если в CheckBox не стоит галочки и включать если CheckBox checked. Как мне отключить сервис. Пробовал синглтон, но даже если я не выходил из приложения приложение крашится.
Запуск сервиса:

```
 private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                    Log.i ("Service status", "Running");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Log.i ("Service status", "Not running");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            //пока так потом добавиться может переделаю
            //SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            boolean isCheck = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
            L.i("key=" + key+"isCheck="+isCheck);
            if(isCheck) {
                mServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MuteService.getInstance().getClass());
                if (!isMyServiceRunning(MuteService.getInstance().getClass())) {
                    getActivity().startService(mServiceIntent);
                }
            } else {
                MuteService.getInstance().stopForeground(false);
            }
        }
```

А вот сам сервис:

```
public class MuteService extends Service implements Observer {

    private static MuteService instanse;

    MuteReceiver mr;

    public MuteService() {
    }

    public static MuteService getInstance() {
        if(instanse== null) {
            instanse = new MuteService();
        }
        return instanse;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mr = new MuteReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.media.action.MICROPHONE_MUTE_CHANGED");
        this.registerReceiver(mr, filter);
        MuteObservable.getInstance().addObserver(this);
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mr);
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finish Work service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground()
    {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
        String channelName = "Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }


    private void sendNotification(boolean isOff) {
        
    }
}
```

Вот Restarter

```
public class Restarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Broadcast Listened", "Service tried to stop");
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, MuteService.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, MuteService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно подразумевается, что если есть метод `startЧегоТо()`, то должен быть и `stopТогоЖе()`.

> If a component starts the service by calling startService() (which
> results in a call to onStartCommand()), the service continues to run
> until it stops itself with stopSelf() or another component stops it by
> calling stopService().

Источник: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

`stopForeground()` же делает из foreground service "обычный", но не останавливает его.

Источник: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#remove-from-foreground